# remove <font> tag using hpricot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot

the html like this:

```
"[font color="#FF0000"]test [font color="#FF0000"]Hello world[/font][/font]"
```

I want to replace the font tag the result like this:

```
test Hello world
```

thanks you

Comment: this will be work:
     content.gsub(/<font .*?>|<\/font>/, '')

Answer (score 1):

Just do 
`doc.inner_text` with hpricot

Sure it will remove all tags. Not only <font>.

Answer (score 0):

doc.search("font").remove?

Comment: I just want to remove the <font> tag but not the content like: <font>test</font> I want to get: test

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove html and only want text **USE**

```
string = "<font color='#FF0000'>test <font color='#FF0000'>Hello world</font></font>"
strip_tags(string)
```

Comment: where is the strip_tags method I just want to remove the <font> tag but not the content like: <font>test</font> I want to get: test 
not other tag

Comment: No This will remove html tags http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#M002165